# Issue with Rad Studio - Delphi 2010 IDE

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2010

Rad Studio 2010 (Delphi 2010) on Windows 7 (64 bit) laptop.

I'm probably going to get a lot of negatives on this one, because I just can't seem to figure out how to word the question title or the question itself......but here it goes

I started to get some issues with my code not running within Rad Studio (Delphi) 2010.

I have been trying to figure out why for several days, working with one installed package after another, trying to decide if it was the culprit or not. After finally uninstalling all packages, and even uninstalling the entire Rad Studio (and re-installing just Rad Studio), I can't seem to figure what can be causing my Delphi IDE to act as it does. I even cleaned the registry of all things related to my component package and Rad Studio (before re-installing just Rad Studio).

Ok, with a fresh copy of just Rad Studio installed I tried to write a simple

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if opendialog1.Execute then
 begin
   ShowMesage(opendialog1.filename);
 end;
end;
```

It compiles and builds without any errors, however,  when I  run the application and click on the button, I get the following message:

> Project1.exe has stopped working A problem caused the program to stop
> working. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution
> is available.

When I click the Close Program button, I get nothing, it just returns to the Delphi 2010 IDE.

If I compile it, I can run the executable.

This has really become a serious issue for me, since I can no longer run or debug code in my IDE without this coming up.

This does not happen if I just create a blank default application without the code, and run it.

Anyone have any suggestions or solutions to my problem?

Comment: Try disabling all your shell extensions. There are known shell extensions that bomb the app if they detect that they are running under a debugger. And showing a file dialog will load shell extensions.

Comment: David has a good idea. I use  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html to get rid of pesky shell extensions.

Comment: Hmmm, thats a great idea. Im kinda a novice when it comes to shell extensions, but ill take a look.

Comment: WOW! I have 254 shell extensions that are all enabled. Where do i begin?  Any suggestions? Do disbale them all and start from there, slowinf enabling each one and testing to see if its the culprit? What are the ramafications of disabling everything? Should i be looking for specific things and disabling those? - Thanks

Comment: Disable everything. Your system will work fine.

Comment: I sort by the column Microsoft:Yes/No, and disable everything Non-Microsoft first.  You can leave TortoiseSVN/TortoiseHG on, they don't crash Delphi. Windows 7 +MSOffice means you have 200+ shell extensions active out of the box. So really it's no big deal having lots of them.

Comment: I disbaled everything. I also disabled everything in MSConfig under startup as well. I rebooted my machine, cranked a freshly installed version of Delphi 2010 up and ran that code and still get the message.......i am totally dumbfounded now - have no idea where to go from here, short of purchasing a new laptop.

Comment: The thing is, is that the executable runs without error. So, something is conflicting with the IDE, cause the application wont run within the IDE.

Comment: I am not sure how you read these, but here are the two event logs from running the application within the IDE. The first one is running the application without clicking the button and opening the dialog. The second one is after clicking the button and opening the dialog, and getting the error.    http://www.bluelinegeocachers.org/delphi/

Comment: I had an issue that sounds similar. The debugger would always break when a file dialog was shown. Only under debugger, never a problem without debugger. It was some AV in the file dialog code. I'm using my own file dialog wrappers (don't like the VCL ones) and my code swallowed this particular exception since the function being called was somewhat optional to proceedings. Sounds quite similar. Disabling all shell extensions did not help. Suddenly one day the problem went away. Perhaps a Windows update? Am I right that in assuming that file dialogs are needed to provoke the problem?

Comment: Your right in assuming that, but im not sure that is the only area that causes the issue. I have been hesitant to reinstall all my third party controls and the application source code (very large) to find it out, but i may have too.

Comment: Reinstall all 3rd party components won't help I think. I think it's an interaction with the system and the debugger. In my case although exceptions were raised, I could continue through them. Sounds as though you are not so lucky.

Comment: It does appear to be associated with 'ShowModal', not just the standard dialogs. Did you get any luck with any of the suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So you have NO third party components or units in any uses clauses?

You tried disabling all anti-virus and malware scanning software temporarily?

Do you have anything like MadExcept or EurekaLog installed? If so, remove them.

If none, then install MadExcept. It will catch exceptions both inside the IDE and inside the target applications.

Secondly, try renaming this registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0`

Rename it to something like:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0_OLD`

Next time you run Delphi 2010, your local-user registry configuration section will be regenerated, and reset to installation-fresh defaults.

Comment: No thirdparty components or units in the uses clause of the application. None in the Win32 library path as well (other than those by default installation of rad studio)

Comment: No MadExcept or EurekaLog either. I should not have to do anything to the registry, since i just did a re-install after uninstalling and cleaning the regestry before hand